# how to reinstall a dead node in rabbitmq cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I have a rabbitmq cluster on rabbit1, rabbit2 and rabbit3. Rabbit2 and Rabbit3 join rabbit1 cluster as RAM node. And rabbit3 is crashed. In rabbit1 and rabbit2, when checking cluster status, the following answer I got.

```
ubuntu@rabbit2:~$ sudo rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node rabbit@rabbit2
[{nodes,[{disc,[rabbit@rabbit1]},{ram,[rabbit@rabbit3,rabbit@rabbit2]}]},
 {running_nodes,[rabbit@rabbit1,rabbit@rabbit2]},
 {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@localhost">>},
 {partitions,[]},
 {alarms,[{rabbit@rabbit1,[]},{rabbit@rabbit2,[]}]}]
```

Now I uninstall rabbitmq3 and install again. Install rabbitmq on rabbit3 successfully.

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/rabbitmq/
sudo apt-get remove rabbitmq-server -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y 
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server -y
```

After installation, I try to add rabbit3 into cluster again. First step, I check cluster status on rabbit3.

```
ubuntu@rabbit3:~$ sudo rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node rabbit@rabbit3
[{nodes,[{disc,[rabbit@rabbit3]}]},
 {running_nodes,[rabbit@rabbit3]},
 {cluster_name,<<"rabbit@localhost">>},
 {partitions,[]},
 {alarms,[{rabbit@rabbit3,[]}]}]
```

Then I override the cookie file

```
ubuntu@rabbit3:~$ sudo sh -c "echo abcdefg > /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie"
ubuntu@rabbit3:~$ sudo cat  /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
abcdefg
```

Check the cluster again.

```
ubuntu@rabbit3:~$ sudo rabbitmqctl cluster_status
Cluster status of node rabbit@rabbit3
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@rabbit3: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@rabbit3]

rabbit@rabbit3:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on rabbit3
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
  * suggestion: hostname mismatch?
  * suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?
  * suggestion: is the Erlang distribution using TLS?

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-25@localhost'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: esZsDxSN6VGbi9JkMSxNZA==
```

rabbit@rabbit3 node cannot be connected, and cannot configure it anymore. I checked the rabbitmq installation document. It introduces how to configure cluster with happy path. 
But if a node is dead, how to re-install it back.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake during installation, in general, I should stop rabbitmq before setting cookie, like

```
 sudo rabbitmqctl stop
sudo sh -c "echo abcd123456 > /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie"
sudo cat  /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
sudo chmod 400 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie 
sudo sh -c "echo abcd123456 > ~/.erlang.cookie"
sudo chmod 400 ~/.erlang.cookie
```